# Applying multiple GroupByKey transforms in a DataFlow job causing windows to be applied multiple times

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a DataFlow job that is subscribed to a PubSub stream of events. We have applied sliding windows of 1 hour with a 10 minute period. In our code, we perform a Count.perElement to get the counts for each element and we then want to run this through a Top.of to get the top N elements.

At a high level:
1) Read from pubSub IO
2) Window.into(SlidingWindows.of(windowSize).every(period)) // windowSize = 1 hour, period = 10 mins
3) Count.perElement 
4) Top.of(n, comparisonFunction)

What we're seeing is that the window is being applied twice so data seems to be watermarked 1 hour 40 mins (instead of 50 mins) behind current time. When we dig into the job graph on the Dataflow console, we see that there are two groupByKey operations being performed on the data:
1) As part of Count.perElement. Watermark on the data from this step onwards is 50 minutes behind current time which is expected.
2) As part of the Top.of (in the Combine.PerKey). Watermark on this seems to be another 50 minutes behind the current time. Thus, data in steps below this is watermarked 1:40 mins behind.

This ultimately manifests in some downstream graphs being 50 minutes late.

Thus it seems like every time a GroupByKey is applied, windowing seems to kick in afresh.

Is this expected behavior? Anyway we can make the windowing only be applicable for the Count.perElement and turn it off after that?

Our code is something on the lines of:

```
final int top = 50;
final Duration windowSize = standardMinutes(60);
final Duration windowPeriod = standardMinutes(10);
final SlidingWindows window = SlidingWindows.of(windowSize).every(windowPeriod);

options.setWorkerMachineType("n1-standard-16");
options.setWorkerDiskType("compute.googleapis.com/projects//zones//diskTypes/pd-ssd");
options.setJobName(applicationName);
options.setStreaming(true);
options.setRunner(DataflowPipelineRunner.class);

final Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

// Get events
final String eventTopic =
    "projects/" + options.getProject() + "/topics/eventLog";
final PCollection<String> events = pipeline
    .apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic(eventTopic));

// Create toplist
final PCollection<List<KV<String, Long>>> topList = events
    .apply(Window.into(window))
    .apply(Count.perElement()) //as eventIds are repeated
    // get top n to get top events
    .apply(Top.of(top, orderByValue()).withoutDefaults());
```

Comment: The system doesn't rewindow at each GroupByKey, but each stage of the computation potentially adds some additional delay, because the Top can't happen until the Count has output all elements in that window. Do you have any details on how much data is being processed? What about numbers from the Count and Top operations?

Comment: We're processing around 80K messages /s at the start. Once it comes down to the Count, we do around 2K messages / s and at the Top we're at the same number (based on what I can see from the Dataflow dashboard).

Comment: I would imagine that Top would then just add a delay of ten minutes (rather than another 50). Count would emit every 10 minutes, so Top should just be 10 minutes behind.

Answer (score 1):

Windowing is not applied each time there is a GroupByKey. The lag you were seeing was likely the result of two issues, both of which should be resolved.

The first was that data that was buffered for later windows at the first group by key was preventing the watermark from advancing, which meant that the earlier windows were getting held up at the second group by key. This has been fixed in the latest versions of the SDK.

The second was that the sliding windows was causing the amount of data to increase significantly. A new optimization has been added which uses the combine (you mentioned Count and Top) to reduce the amount of data.

Comment: Thanks will try that. Do you know when the update to the SDK is expected to be rolled out? We don't mind pulling the latest changes from master and trying them out :-)

Comment: The latest release on Maven (0.4.150710) should have the mentioned improvements. If you try updating let us know how it goes.